# How to prove that A does not have supremum in B

Tags: real-analysis

Given two sets

$$A=\{p\in\Bbb Q^+\mid p^2 < 2\}$$

$$B=\{p\in\Bbb Q^+\mid p^2 > 2\}$$

I have proved that no element is $A$ can be supremum of $A$. But how do i say no element of $B$ is lub of $A$

Comment: you can see that the supremum of $A$ is the infemum of $B$ is $\sqrt(2)$ witch is not a rational number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that sets $A, B$ *essentially* form a Dedekind cut which represents the irrational number $\sqrt{2}$. And then $\sqrt{2}$ is the supremum of $A$ and infimum of $B$.

But it is possible to prove the claim without using any ideas about irrational numbers. What is required here is to show that $A$ has no greatest member and $B$ has no least member. This is not difficult. Clearly $1 \in A, 2 \in B$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrarily given and let's choose a positive integer $n$ such that $n > 4/\epsilon$ so that $1/n < \epsilon/4$. Now consider the numbers $$1, 1 + 1/n, 1 + 2/n, 1 + 3/n, \cdots, 1 + n/n = 2\tag{1}$$ In the above list the first number lies in $A$ and last number lies in $B$ and the list has numbers in ascending order. If you note carefully the definition of $A, B$ you will note that they have a curious property: if $x \in A$ and $y \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$ and $y < x$ then $y \in A$ and if $x \in B$ and $y \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$ with $y > x$ then $y \in B$. Because of the above property it follows that if we look at the numbers of the list $(1)$ there will be a last in this list which belongs to $A$ and the next one in the list will lie in $B$. Also the difference between consecutive members of the list $(1)$ is $1/n$. Hence we have found two numbers $x, y$ such that $1 \leq x < y \leq 2$ and $x \in A, y \in B$ and $y - x < 1/n < \epsilon/4$.

Now we can see that $x + y \leq 4$ and $y - x < \epsilon / 4$ so that $$0 < y^{2} - x^{2} < \epsilon$$ or $$(y^{2} - 2) + (2 - x^{2}) < \epsilon\tag{2}$$ Since $x \in A, y \in B$ we see that both $y^{2} - 2$ and $2 - x^{2}$ are positive and by equation $(2)$ they are both less than $\epsilon$.

Hence we have proved that *if $\epsilon > 0$ is any arbitrary rational number then there are rational numbers $x, y$ with $x \in A, y \in B$ such that $$2 - x^{2} < \epsilon, y^{2} - 2 < \epsilon\tag{3}$$*

From the above *it follows that $A$ has no greatest member and $B$ has no least member*. *How??* Suppose that $A$ has a greatest member $k$. Now $k \in A$ so $2 - k^{2} > 0$ and let $\epsilon = 2 - k^{2}$. And we can now choose an $x \in A$ such that $2 - x^{2} < \epsilon = 2 - k^{2}$ so that $x^{2} > k^{2}$. Since both $x, k$ are positive this means that $x > k$. So we have $x \in A, x > k$ and this contradicts that $k$ is the greatest member of $A$. Again let's assume that $B$ has a least member $k$. Then since $k \in B$ we have $\epsilon = k^{2} - 2 > 0$ and hence by what we have establish earlier there is a member $y \in B$ such that $y^{2} - 2 < \epsilon = k^{2} - 2$ or $y^{2} < k^{2}$ and since both $y, k$ are positive it follows that $y < k$ which contradicts that $k$ is the least member of $B$.

Now if $x \in A, y \in B$ then $x < y$ and hence every element of $B$ is an upper bound for $A$. Suppose that there is some $k \in B$ such that $\sup A = k$. This means that no number less than $k$ is an upper bound for $A$. But as we have seen above there are members in $B$ which are less than $k$ and by definition of $B$ these are upper bounds of $A$. So we have a contradiction and no member of $B$ is a supremum of $A$.

Comment: @Gathdi: Yes this one is from my favorite Hardy. This is by far the best argument I have seen. Especially because this argument is so analysis oriented in nature (compared to the algebraic argument of egreg's answer which you have accepted)

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no rational number whose square is $2$, $B$ is the set of upper bounds for $A$.

Now, for every $p\in B$ you can find $q\in B$ such that $q<p$. This proves $A$ has no least upper bound.

Proof. Given $q\in B$, let's look for $r\in\mathbb{Q}^+$ such that $p-r\in B$, that is, $(p-r)^2>2$ and $p-r>0$. The first inequality becomes
$$
p^2-2pr+r^2>2
$$
and it will be satisfied if $p^2-2pr>2$, that is,
$$
r<\frac{p^2-2}{2p}
$$
So just take
$$
r=\min\left(\frac{p^2-2}{4p},\frac{p}{2}\right)
$$

Comment: What do you mean to say take r = min( )...I mean i know the notation but i did not get deeper meaning. why r should be less than p?

Comment: @Gathdi We need $r<p$ so that $p-r\in\mathbb{Q}^+$. Actually I forgot a /2.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Can you prove that $B$ does not have a smallest element?

If you can, then the argument is as follows: suppose that $A$ has a supremum in $B$, call it $x$. This means that $x$ is the smallest upper bound of $A$. But, we know that $B$ does not have a smallest element, i.e., there exists $y\in B$ such that $y<x$. This contradicts the fact that $A$ has a supremum in $B$.